# How to connect a 14-30r outlet with only three wires?

Tags: electrical, receptacle

I am trying to wire a 14-30r receptacle.  I only have 3 wires (black, red, and ground).  There is a system ground and equipment ground on the wiring diagram.  Do these both attach to the ground?

Comment: What are you plugging into this receptacle?

Answer (score 5):

A NEMA 14-30R requires four conductors.  Two ungrounded (hot) conductors, one grounded (neutral) conductor, and one equipment grounding conductor.

Both the grounded (neutral), and equipment grounding conductors are connected to ground. But only at the service equipment.  Outside of the service equipment they are separate conductors, and **cannot** be interchanged or interconnected.

Answer (score 1):

If you only have three wires, then you cannot install a 14-30.   Consider instead a 5-30 (120v), 6-30 (240v), or 10-30 (unsafe 120/240).

14-30 is the safe 120/240 outlet with separate neutral and ground (required by code in most jurisdictions)

10-30 is its older counterpart that combines ground and neutral.

Or consider running another conductor (white) for Neutral.  Then you may have the 14-30 which you desire.

Comment: Running a new neutral is likely to cause 310.10(H)/300.3(B) issues -- you *can* run a separate EGC of the appropriate gauge though.

Comment: If it is run in conduit you could pull another conductor in. But if it is a typical dwelling unit that is wired in NM cable the code doesn't allow for a separate conductor from the NM cable to act as a neutral. Even a separate EGC would not be an option since the ground wire in this old cable is most likely bare and could not be used as a Neutral.

Answer (score 0):

I would never misuse ground as neutral.

The neutral is there to give the appliance 120v (it already has 240v).  I would take a hard look at the appliance: "why does this appliance need 240v *and also* 120v?" Often, only a few watts of 120v is necessary to power a clock, controls or convenience lighting (so you can use common 120v bulbs instead of hard-to-find 240v bulbs).  If you can live without that feature, done.

Otherwise consider "hacking" the appliance: either get rid of the 120v requirement (e.g. wire it to use 240v bulbs) or install a transformer that makes sufficient 120v from 240v.  That's often done in the 480v world when a bit of 120v is needed for controls.